# How to Stop Odoo 15 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, server, odoo, erp

I already try some answers on the internet to stop Odoo that running on my Ubuntu server, but it didn't work. I can't kill the process by pressing `Ctrl + C` because right now I use another terminal session and I can't find the Odoo log file for version 15.

I run Odoo by using this command from the root Odoo folder

```
python3 odoo-bin -c odoo.conf
```

If I run this command again using another session after Odoo is running, I get this kind of error message

```
Exception in thread odoo.service.httpd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

When I list all services that run on my server, there is no Odoo service running, but when I open the domain, I know the Odoo server is running.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer, how to kill the process. This answer is similar to [Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12074396/ismail-h-rana), but I don't know why his answer not working. I have to list all services.

Run this command to list all running service

```
ps aux||grep
```

Find a service with command `python3 odoo-bin -c odoo.conf` and kill this process with the PID number

```
sudo kill -9 [PID_NUMBER]
```

Example

```
sudo kill -9 26421
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `kill` command to kill the process if you know the process id. Also `sudo killall python` should kill every python script running in the server

Comment: do you have any log file for odoo 15 in the server?

Comment: That is my other question. I can't find Odoo log file for 15 version.

Answer (score 0):

in the session that runs the first odoo, ctrl + c ends the Odoo instance, if the command you say is exactly the one you use.

If you want to run multiple Odoo session you can select a free port for the second session.

```
python3 odoo-bin -c odoo.conf -p 8080
```

If you want to close the server from another terminal you need the PID of the odoo process. Or you can use htop, here you can find the process and kill it.

A better way to work from different terminals is to use screen, which gives you access to virtual terminals that can run in the background and can be pulled to the foreground from another terminal than the one where it was created.

read here how to work with screen: https://linuxhint.com/linux-screen-command-tutorial/

Comment: I know how to kill the process with `Ctrl + C` and run multiple Odoo with multiple ports. My question is, how to end the process using another terminal session.

Comment: with the pid of the process. but use screen on your server so you can just switch between open tty's, much easier. Or run Odoo as a service on the server, like it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and use the following command:

`ps aux | grep './odoo-bin -c odoo.conf'`

Take the **PID**, In my case: **56608**

Then kill the process:(Replace the PID with yours)

`sudo kill -9 56608`

[image]

Comment: Alternative: You can use `lsof | grep 8069`  -- replace 8069 with your port. then find out the LISTENING port with python and take PID and kill the process.

Comment: When I try to kill the process, the result message is `kill: (MY_PID_NUMBER): No such process`. It seems like the PID number always change

Comment: @NMNaufaldo Maybe you chose the wrong number.

Comment: No, I have already tried multiple times.